# Uncaught TypeError: Object.observe is not a function at pesticide_page.js:19

Tags: syntax-error, console.log, typeerror

I get this error message in terminal in every site:

```
'Uncaught TypeError: Object.observe is not a function     at pesticide_page.js:19'
```

I tried to uninstall pesticide package using `npm uninstall pesticide` but still got this error message.

Here are my version numbers:

```
$ nvm --version
0.33.11
$ node -v
v8.11.4
$ nvm list
->      v8.11.4
         system
default -> stable (-> v8.11.4)
node -> stable (-> v8.11.4) (default)
stable -> 8.11 (-> v8.11.4) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/carbon (-> v8.11.4)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.14.4 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.11.4
$ npm -v
6.4.1
```

Thsi is in the 'pestiCIde_page.js' file:

```
Object.observe(_pesticide, function (changes) {
    var newVal = changes[0].object.state;
    localStorage._pesticide = newVal;
    update(newVal);
});

update(window._pesticide.state);
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

For people facing the same situation in a browser environment with a pesticide plugin.

**Restart the browser after removing pesticide** and the error doesn't get shown again.

1.Remove the pesticide plugin

2.Restart the browser.

If ur browser is chrome as in my case:
go to addressbar and type: **chrome:restart** and click enter.